# Javascript equivalent to C# SHA512

Tags: javascript, encoding, cryptojs

I'm having trouble converting this C# function that takes in input and converts it to hash and returns a byte array, to Javascript.

```
    public static byte[] Sha512(string input)
    {
        using (SHA512 sha = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            return sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        }
    }
```

Input in this example is: "1pImY_gls.hu". The C# function correctly returns:

```
[57, 115, 234, 22, 47, 82, 252, 77, 133, 181, 138, 214, 32, 3, 155, 216, 181, 246, 130, 106, 160, 198, 73, 110, 50, 68, 56, 18, 120, 152, 231, 55, 3, 14, 144, 21, 84, 92, 237, 190, 6, 124, 51, 221, 95, 195, 73, 168, 100, 167, 84, 185, 167, 142, 184, 72, 243, 120, 213, 64, 176, 215, 15, 25]
```

My current Javascript function converts the input to:

```
[51, 57, 55, 51, 101, 97, 49, 54, 50, 102, 53, 50, 102, 99, 52, 100, 56, 53, 98, 53, 56, 97, 100, 54, 50, 48, 48, 51, 57, 98, 100, 56, 98, 53, 102, 54, 56, 50, 54, 97, 97, 48, 99, 54, 52, 57, 54, 101, 51, 50, 52, 52, 51, 56, 49, 50, 55, 56, 57, 56, 101, 55, 51, 55, 48, 51, 48, 101, 57, 48, 49, 53, 53, 52, 53, 99, 101, 100, 98, 101, 48, 54, 55, 99, 51, 51, 100, 100, 53, 102, 99, 51, 52, 57, 97, 56, 54, 52, 97, 55, 53, 52, 98, 57, 97, 55, 56, 101, 98, 56, 52, 56, 102, 51, 55, 56, 100, 53, 52, 48, 98, 48, 100, 55, 48, 102, 49, 57]
```

I'm fairly new to encoding so I'm not sure how I should proceed. In this example I'm using crypto but I have no problem using crypto-js instead.
My current Javascript function is:

```
    convertPassword: function(password){
        convertPassword: function(password){
        var encoder = new TextEncoder()

        var sha512 = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(password).digest("hex")
        
        return encoder.encode(sha512)
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# code you are digesting your hashed password in "latin1" charset encoding. In your node.js code, you've set it to digest in HEX. You need to change that to "latin1" and your problem should be solved. So in order to have the same output...

This line:

```
var sha512 = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(password).digest("hex")
```

Should look like this:

```
var sha512 = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(password).digest("latin1")
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: Argument of type '"latin1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BinaryToTextEncoding'.